# how to change the output in visual studio code from terminal to output ? i tried but i'm getting command not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
[Running] python -u "d:\OTHER FILES D\PYTHON ALL FOLD\VISUAL STUDIO PROJECTS\VSC code challenges problems\workspace_code_challenges.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.045 seconds
```

[image]

Comment: When you installed python, did you check the option to add it in the system PATH env variable? If you did that try to restart the pc, if no add it.

Comment: @AlexLucaci how to add it ? can you show it step by step ?

Comment: Updated code formatting and added image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search for `Edit environment variables for your account` with the windows search option
2. In the system variables, double click on `Path` -> `New` and add the path of your Python installation which is usual on

> C:\Users(Your logged in User)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

This is for Python version 3.6, you can adjust the path for your Python version

You should also add

> C:\Users(Your logged in User)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts

3. Click `Ok` and try again now, if it's not working, reboot the computer and try again to see if you encounter the same error.

Comment: tried both the ways not working still getting "python not recognized"

Comment: Did you find your Python installation folder?